# "Have to" structure

Tags: verbs

As I know we can use "Have to" in Simple and Perfect Tenses. Can we use it in Continuous tenses? If I am not wrong, the following sentences are in Present Continuous Tense with "Have to" Structure in it:

- She has to be working with me.
- She is not have to be working with me.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a preference thing on the first sentence, but if the intent is that it is necessary for her to work with me, then I would phrase it as "She must be working with me" or simply "She must work with me".

As for the second sentence, that doesn't work at all.  Using is and have to be in the same verb sequence doesn't work.  If you want to keep nearly the same structure, you could say "She does not have to be working with me".  I'm having a hard time finding the words to describe why this is better, but I know it is.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use 'have to' in Continuous tenses 
your sentences are not grammatical (has to be working ???) => has to work
the second also false grammatically